# Apache Camel onExceptionOccurred component not redelivering as mentioned times

Tags: apache-camel

I have an Apache Camel route which invokes restlet component. To better understand what is happening at runtime I also keep the execution state in a database (number of retries, last execution state). I would like to use the redelivery mechanism from the exception handler but which performs some processing on every failure to update my database record.

```
<bean class="com.tcl.ExceptionOccurredRefProcessor" id="exProc" />
<camelContext errorHandlerRef="eh">
<errorHandler id="eh" onExceptionOccurredRef="exProc"> <redeliveryPolicy 
            maximumRedeliveries="3" maximumRedeliveryDelay="2000" 
            retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN" />
</errorHandler>
<to uri="-------"/> //Invoke rest service
<onException id="_onException1" onExceptionOccurredRef="exProc" useOriginalMessage="true">
                <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
                <handled>
                    <simple>true</simple>
                </handled>
                ...........
   </onException>
</camelContext>
```

For this I tried to use onExceptionOccurred component with redelivery component and referred on camelContext as in above code but the message got delivered only once and stopped the execution.

**Any suggestions please?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all: the code you pasted is a bit confusing because there is no Camel route, just a plain `to` element that cannot be alone in the Camel context.

However, I guess your problem is a "hidden" Camel handling. As documented in the [Camel Docs of the Exception Clause](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html#ExceptionClause-ConfiguringRedeliveryPolicyredeliveroptions), the **`onException` clause overrides the `maximumRedeliveries` to 0 by default** unless you explicitly set the option.

```
<onException>
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception> // max. redelivery = 0
</onException>

<onException>
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception> 
    <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="3"/> // max. redelivery = 3
</onException>
```

I an not sure about the other redelivery options like `maximumRedeliveryDelay`, but at least the `maximumRedeliveries` is overridden if not explicitly set.